# Continuity of Functions defined from a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\overline{\Omega}\subset\mathbb{R}^{N}$ be a compact set and $T<\infty$. Assume $f : \overline{\Omega}\times(0,T)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and sastifies
(A) $\forall x\in\overline{\Omega}, \sup\limits_{t\in(0,T)}|f(x,t)|<\infty$
(B) $\forall t\in(0,T), \sup\limits_{x\in\overline{\Omega}}|f(x,t)|<\infty$

Is it possible to show that a function defined as $\bar{f}:=\sup\limits_{t\in(0,T)}f(\,\cdot\,,t)$ to be a continuous function in $\overline{\Omega}$? I would like to apply this problem for my PDE research so any help (or counterexample) will be useful. (Remark : I know that $\sup\limits_{x\in\overline{\Omega}}|f(x,\,\cdot\,)|$ is a continuous function in $(0,T)$ since $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact.)

Thank you very much!

Comment: @LucioTanzini Thank you very much for your idea. I have a problem of defining $f$ at the end of interval ($t=0$ and $t=T$). Do you have a rough sketch to show it? If I add Holder continuity assumption then this becomes trivial but I am not sure this will work in this case.

Comment: Would you be okay with showing that if it was on $[0,T]$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, you can see a good result here https://williewong.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/continuity-of-the-infimum.

You do not even need that result as $\overline{\Omega}\times[0,T]$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ which means $f$ attains its maximum at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider the following counterexample.

Let $f:(0,1)\times [0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a function defined as $f(x,y)=\text{arctan}(y/x)$.
Then, $\bar{f}$ is not continous on $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a good counterexample for me. To be fair, my original goal is to show that $\sup\limits_{t\in[0,T]}\sup\limits_{x\in\overline{\Omega}}|f(x,t)|<\infty$ so maybe my claim here is a bit too strong.

Comment: I think that is false as well, a counterexample can be built in a similar way